# Projective tensor product $\ell^2 \hat{\otimes}_\pi \ell^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products

In Ryan *Introduction to Tensor Products of Banach spaces*, Example 2.10, it is shown that the space $\ell^2 \hat{\otimes}_\pi \ell^2$, where $\hat{\otimes}_\pi$ denotes the projective tensor product and $\ell^2$ the usual space of square-summable sequences, contains $\ell^1$ as a subspace, and that $\ell^1$ is complemented in $\ell^2 \hat{\otimes}_\pi \ell^2$, that is, a subspace $M$ exists such that $\ell^2 \hat{\otimes}_\pi \ell^2 = \ell^1 \oplus M$. Is anything known about this space $M$? I'd be also intersted if there are other references that discuss the space $\ell^2 \hat{\otimes}_\pi \ell^2$ in more detail.

Comment: Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2601632/description-of-projective-and-injective-tensor-products-ell2-otimes-ell2?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\ell^2$ has approximation property (AP) since it possess a Schauder basis. $\ell^2$ also has the Radon-Nikodym property (RNP) since every reflexive Banach space has RNP. You may deduce the following from the more general theorems in Ryan's book: If a Banach space $X$ is reflexive and has AP, then

- $X\hat{\otimes}_{\epsilon}X^* = K(X)$, the space of compact operators on $X$.
- $X\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}X^* = N(X)$, the space of nuclear operators on $X$
- $(X\hat{\otimes}_{\epsilon}X^*)^* = X\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}X^*$
- $(X\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}X^*)^* = B(X)$ the space of all bounded operators on $X$.

Thus, $\ell^2\hat{\otimes}_{\epsilon}\ell^2 = K(\ell^2)$, and $\ell^2\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}\ell^2 = N(\ell^2)$, which is the space of the trace class operators on $\ell^2$.

For the other question, given a complemented subspace $V$ of a Banach space $X$, $V$ may not have a unique complement. However, the complemented $\ell^1$ subspace given in Ryan's book is the closed linear span of the tensor diagonal $(e_k\otimes e_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$, where $(e_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ can be chosen any orthonormal basis for $\ell^2$. Also, a particular projection (call it $P$) is also given in the book. One may simply define $M$ to be the range of the projection $I-P$, where $I$ is the identity map.

Comment: Thanks! For the second part I was hoping for a more concrete description of $M$ than $M=(1-P)\ell^2\hat{\otimes}_\pi\ell^2$, but perhaps there isn't any.

Comment: Consider the elements of $\ell^2\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}\ell^2$ as infinite matrices. Let $M_0$ contain all matrices with finitely many nonzero entries that has $0$'s on the diagonal. $M$ is the closure of $M_0$ in $\ell^2\hat{\otimes}_{\pi}\ell^2$.